# Format date for mysql insert

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Im using LOAD DATA INFILE to import a csv file, the files date format is `29/11/2010` and the database format is `2010-11-29`, what can i use to format the date inside the query?

I've tried str_to_date:

```
SET date_start = STR_TO_DATE(@from_date,'%Y-%m-%d'),
```

but that only inserts `0000-00-00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MySQL 4.x**

`LOAD DATA` will try to insert your dates as they are. It isn't aware about format and in common case you can not apply some post-processing to your fields (well, different from some format which is allowed inside `LOAD DATA` syntax itself) - and you can not adjust your values via `SET` keyword like in `MySQL 5.x`

Instead you can do following steps:

- Declare your table's column as `VARCHAR`. Let it name be `record_date`
- Do your `LOAD DATA` query. It will load your dates into `record_date` column
- Add new column to your table, let it be `temp_date` - with type `DATE`: `ALTER TABLE t ADD temp_date DATE`
- Update your `temp_date` column: `UPDATE t SET temp_date = STR_TO_DATE(record_date, '%d/%m/%Y')`
- Drop your `VARCHAR` date column: `ALTER TABLE t DROP record_date`
- Finally, rename column with correct `DATE` type to original one: `ALTER TABLE t CHANGE temp_date record_date DATE`

As result, you'll have your dates loaded into your table as `DATE` date type. Replace `record_date` to the name which your original column has.

**MySQL 5.x**

You can use [`SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) keyword and natively replace procedure, described above. So just do:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv'
INTO TABLE t
(@date)
SET record_date=STR_TO_DATE(@date, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

-sample above is for one column and you'll need to add others (if they exist). Date column name is also `record_date` - so change it to actual name too.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
update tablename SET date_start = date_format(@from_date,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATE_FORMAT()` . It will Formats the date value according to the format string.  [**Mysql**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
date_format(@from_date,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT` is for formatting dates and has nothing to do with `LOAD DATA` format conversion